# db.SaveChanges() returns 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.'

Tags: azure, tcp, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

In our web application (running on Azure), the user uploads several XML-files. These files are saved in Azure Cloud Storage and a record is inserted in a table.
We also have a web job (written in C#) that is looking at that table and when a new record is inserted it downloads the XML-file from the storage, parses it and saves the data to multiple tables.
This runs fine for over 2 years. Recently our client is uploading larger XML-files (300+ MB) which take longer to process and we ran into `time-out errors`. After increasing the time-out we got `Out-of-Memory errors`.
We're now using the `BulkSaveChanges` from `ZZProjects` and we don't get `OOM-exceptions` anymore and as a bonus, the saving is now taking about 17 minutes instead of 3+ hours.

With some (about 10%) of the large files we get these kinds of errors:

```
2018-02-23 01:19:06,993 [1] DEBUG Services.DeclarationService - Ready to save to the db
2018-02-23 01:21:10,778 [1] ERROR DataAccess.ApplicationUoW - 
Error in saving data: A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. 
  (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. 
  (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) 
   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.SNIWritePacket(SNIHandle handle, SNIPacket packet, UInt32& sniError, Boolean canAccumulate, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni(Boolean canAccumulate)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode, Boolean canAccumulate)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName, Boolean shouldReconnect)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginTransaction()
   at DbContextExtensions..(BulkOperation )
   at Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EntityBulkOperation`1.(Action`1 )
   at DbContextExtensions.[](DbContext , Action`1 )
   at DbContextExtensions.[](DbContext , IEnumerable`1 , Action`1 , List`1 )
   at Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.BulkSaveChanges.(DbContext , List`1 , List`1 , Action`1 )
   at DbContextExtensions.(DbContext , Boolean , Action`1 , Boolean )
ClientConnectionId:####
Error Number:10054,State:0,Class:20
ClientConnectionId before routing:####
Routing Destination:####,11003
```

I've been searching the internet for days now and I see similar issues but they are mostly related to client software like `MSSMS` and are solved by reopening the client software. I'm not using client software locally. Everything runs on Azure.

We do have a manual retry mechanism in our web app and when I retry the failed XML-file it keeps failing. But when I run my web job locally (it's just an `.exe`) but still connecting to my Azure SQL Database and Azure Storage the failed XML-files do get processed.

I already understand this is a very generic error. It would be nice if I could get some more details about the reason why this error is thrown. But I can't find any more logging on Azure.

I'm saving one object which might have multiple child objects, making it very hard to split the object and save smaller portions.

Although Azure is restarting several times a week (`very nice on a production environment ;(`) this is not happening when the above problem occurs.

Any suggestions or advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Transient connection errors are expected in Azure, you should look at transient fault handling application block. This may be being killed due to throttling. See https://odehne.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/how-to-accept-connection-loss-and-sql-client-exceptions-in-sql-azure-and-still-live-happily-ever-after/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680901(v=pandp.50).aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-bjBW1nEWNKCnFcPXq46Thg&tduid=(dc09c6504c16402a19ad129346482c4d)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-bjBW1nEWNKCnFcPXq46Thg)()

Comment: Also see this MSDN Blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/04/16/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/

Comment: Thanks @SteveFord for your help. Using your suggestions I did some more research and found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456835(v=vs.113).aspx It seems EF6 doesn't need the package just some configuration. I added `SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient",() => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));` to my `DbConfiguration` and started my multiday webjob again. Didn't help got several `A transport-level error has occurred` again. I think I'm going to suggest to my client to move away from Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Azure Support the problem was found. In my error log the connectionId is was listed so they could look at it very closely. They could see the connection was opened, some data was retrieved and then the connection was idle for more than 30 minutes. Because of this, Azure closes the connection.

During this idle moment our application is doing some stuff and with the large files this takes more than 30 minutes. The Azure engineer suggested we should add a 'KeepAlive' method and call it every 5 minute to keep the connection open.

In our unit of work class I added `private readonly Timer _timer = new Timer(5 * 60 * 1000);` and in its constructor:

```
_timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => KeepAlive();
_timer.Start();
```

Our KeepAlive method is just getting the rows of a small table:

```
private void KeepAlive()
{
    var dummy = _context.BankAccounts.AsNoTracking().ToList().Count;
    Console.WriteLine($@"{DateTime.Now} KeepAlive");
}
```

We could enhance this with `.Take(1)` to get only 1 row.

After adding this we could finally complete our large files.

Hopefully this helps somebody else. It took us weeks ;)

Comment: The only reason you would need to have a connection open for 30 minutes is if you were also holding a transaction open for 30 minutes. Otherwise, you should only open the connection as late as possible and close it as early as possible.  There shouldn't be 30 seconds of idle time for a connection, and def not 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

About processing those large XML files, have you considered splitting them before processing them? Since you never had issues when the files were smaller, you may consider having these files split on the client side before getting uploaded to Azure storage as shown on [this](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/) article:

Comment: Thanks Alberto. We did look into splitting the files but that makes it extra complex due to the content of the files. I'm now looking into keeping the connection alive by doing a simple select every 5 minutes in my Unit of Work. Last night it did successfully completed 2 files but stalled after that. I've made a small adjustment and the process is running again. I'll let you know if it succeeds or not.